# ASP.NET: Password Recovery link on a LogIn control requires a user to login

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to test this out on my site but it doesn't quite work because I have to be logged in to go to this page.

Is there a configuration setting that I haven't set or set incorrectly?

EDIT:  rm's answer led me to this [link from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178335.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adding to Arjan's answer, the settings for page permissions are in your web.config file.

you should do something like this:

```
<configuration>
   <location path="YourPage.aspx">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: When <allow users="*"/> is <allow users="?"/>, it works.  Can you edit your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Cool; I didn't know you could set <location path="... to point to a specific file. Always thought it was folders only...

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the page containing the PasswordRecovery control is in a accesscontrolled folder.

So when trying to reach that page, you're being redirected to the login page again...